# Magento 2 Success page with trailing slash and without

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

> We are experiencing some conversion tracking issues in our Magento
>   2.3.3 installation.

**We are using Native checkout with Paypal Payments Pro Hosted and Paypal Express.**

We are having 2 versions of Success page being generate /success/ and /success

**See the image below of 10 sample orders.**

[image: sample orders]

I can not find any relation between which orders hit /success/ and which hit /success it seems completely random. Orders hitting /success are not being tracked properly by google adwords/analytics conversion tracking. We do not get conversion data.

I have checked for patterns of the below:
Payment methods, country, logged in or guest, shipping method, order amount

I can't find any pattern that's resulting in certain customers hitting /success or /success/

Does anyone have any experience with this or what might be causing this issue?

**Thanks**

Comment: Have you found any clue about this issue?